# Finding and setting the position of camera in three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I use THREE.OrbitalControl.js

```
Control = new THREE.OrbitControls(Camera, Renderer.domElement);
```

and rotate move the mesh to find the position of camera I console the `Camera.position` and `Camera.rotation` in animate function, but while copying those value to the camera I don't get the same position while copying the values.

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    Renderer.render(Scene, Camera);
    THREEx.WindowResize(Renderer, Camera);
    console.log("position");
    console.log(Camera.position);
    console.log("rotation");
    console.log(Camera.rotation);
}
```

Comment: are you saying that if you were to take the values logged to the console, and explicitly set the camera position to those values (i.e. camera.position.x = x; camera.position.y = y, etc.) then the camera is not looking at the same place it was when those same values were logged?

Comment: Yes  . so i copied the values of the Camera rotation yet it is not working

Comment: cc
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482231/camera-position-changes-in-three-orbitcontrols-in-three-js/37483235#37483235?newreg=c0e8f1645be1489abbab7866d925197c

Answer (score 0):

You have two vectors:

```
camera.position
controls.target
```

To move the camera (and also the camera target) you need to change booth (if the camera.target vector changed).