# Camera position changes in `THREE.OrbitControls` in three.js

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js, position

The `THREE.OrbitControls` working fine when loaded with the initial camera position, but when the camera position and camera rotation is changed using a button click. the position of camera changes but on clicking the canvas to rotate the camera on new view the position of camera suddenly changes

**Camera:**

```
 Camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, Width / Height, 0.1, 1000);
 Camera.position.set(170, 120, 400); //intial cam position
 Scene.add(Camera); 


Camera.position.set(30, 167, 81);
Camera.rotation.set(-0.149, 0.3, 0.045); //final cam position
```

**Orbit controls:**

```
controlz = new THREE.OrbitControls(Camera, Renderer.domElement);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunjayakumar07/wzw96sau/)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you use `THREE.OrbitControls` and you want to change the camera target or position you should do like this:

## Update position:

```
camera.position.set(-0.041, 1.9, -1.21);
controls.update();
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/r09y6218/)**

## Update target:

```
controls.target.set(30, 167, 81);
controls.update();
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/w7jorg0y/)**

## Reset camera

To reset the camera to the initial position you can do:

```
controls.reset();
```

Comment: i have update with a fiddle, can you have a look at it

Comment: I think i need to update the center of the controls ??

Comment: on rotating the camera on the first time it is loaded ,and after the click is different, how to achieve it

Comment: Doestn't the fiddle in my answer demonstrate exactly that what you are asking for?

Comment: It doesn't work for camera rotation; 

camera.position.set(-0.041, 1.9, -1.21);
camera.rotation.z = 0.785398;
controls.update();

Comment: one issue that I faced is - when I used `controls.target = position`, then the mesh where the position is derived from doesn't move on orbit - causing weird behavior.

Comment: @Gangula Not totally sure what you mean by that. Why should the Mesh rotate? If you want to rotate the mesh, this should be done independently from setting the orbit controls. Maybe you should provide a working example (for example in a Fiddle) to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: I meant that the correct way to set target to orbitControls is use `.target.set`. But I used `.target = ` - causing weird behavior and which is fixed it by using `.set`. I don't have a issue right now, I just wanted to comment here for future viewers and reference.

Comment: The examples no longer work. Errors in console.

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian Updated those examples. Should be working fine again now...